# Customising Contact Form 7 in wordpress 

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 in my word press. Here i have created 2 forms namely form 1, form 2. when form 1 data's are filled and submitted it need to go to form 2 page.

Here i don't want to send mail while submitting form 1. so i need to stop sending email to form1 and after submitting form 1 it needs to go to form 2 page. if i submit form 2 i need to send an email . I have assigned both forms to separate pages. How to do it?

any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the contact management page of Form 1 you will find the **Additional Settings** area near the bottom. Simply insert two lines into it:

```
demo_mode: on
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

1. With `demo_mode` setting you can stop e-mail sending. Additionally all the validations inlcuding Akismet will be done on the form fields.
2. You can use the `on_sent_ok` JavaScript action hook to run one-line JavaScript code after succesful submitting. With `location` parameter you can specify the URL you want to redirect to.

[image: CF7 Additional Settings]

Finally you may want to hide the pop up messages on Form 1 page. For this you can use e.g. some `css` styling:

```
<form-id> .wpcf7-response-output {
    display: none;
}
```

---

Tested on:

- Contact Form 7 Version 3.3.1
- WordPress Version 3.4.2